# How to share files on master node to executors in Spark, How to use --files argument?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Can someone please explain, How can i ship my files in master to all executors using --files argument in spark-submit

```
/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --queue development --conf spark.memory.offHeap.enabled=true --conf spark.memory.offHeap.size=128G --files /keras/mnist.npz
```

But this gives me error. I am new to spark.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you didn't specify the application class on this command. Find more details on [Running Spark On Yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).